# Is there a way or method or pinning your breakout components window(not sure what it's technical name is) from disappearing in VS Code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, editor

Image of the Breakout and my inability to reach my components

[image: Image of the Breakout and my inability to reach my components]

Hi there, I've a particularly long list on components in a C# script and when I try and look through to see which components are null and whatnot, it keeps disappearing cause my mouse leaves the general area, is there any assistance someone could provide for preventing this? Like pinning the window to a tab or something would be great or just someway to stop it from disappearing so quickly. I don't the actually term for this window as well which makes searching for help a little more difficult.

Comment: Have you considered using the watch window and putting your variable there

Comment: Yeah this is a good case for adding that object to the watch window.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The watch helps a lot. Wish there was a better way with the components window but nevertheless thanks